# Website hosting

Tags: web, hosting

When I create simple website in one`.html`file, I know I'm able to easily put the code to free web hosting and just create my own website.
But I'm completely lost with php files. When using (even paid) web hosting service, does it provide you some kind of online version of database my php files can communicate with? How does this advanced-online hosting work?

Comment: I've voted to close this question as off-topic, but quickly: it depends. But yes, you can find (many many) hosting providers who provide a ready-made PHP and MySQL/other db runtime. You just upload your PHP files, and plug in to their database config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you will need paid hosting to be able to run PHP files and manage one or more MySQL databases (reasonably). Hosting isn't that expensive, though. If you just plan on having a little website for yourself, don't purchase the *super duper package*; upgrade to it once it would be necessary, which might be some years down the road.

Web hosts offer different kinds of support, but PHP and MySQL are fairly standard. Usually, everything will communicate with the same things, i.e. you will set up a MySQL database on your host and your PHP files will be coded such that they work with that database. Everything is on your web host, just like how HTML files can only reference files on your webserver (as opposed to your computer, which is not possible).